# Jquery/Javascript timer that doesn't restart on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, timer, countdown

this is my first question on SO :)

I need a timer in jQuery or javascript that will countdown 15 minutes, and than show a close button. Also, when user refreshes the page it should not reset, but either continue where it stopped or finish countdown not depending on whether user came back, i.e. if the user returns after 16 minutes, he will see message and a close button.  Any suggestions?

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: anything that can come on my mind is to use a local cache to preserve timer value

Comment: For this you would need either `localStorage` support or cookies and serverside stuff

Comment: If it's important the user cannot circumvent the close after 15 minutes I wouldn't do it in JS, the user can just manipulate the cookie or localStorage. You'd still need a timer to show the time left but checking if the time has passed should be done server side as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it uses [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) which you have to download and include in your scripts and works on all current browsers:

```
/* get the time passed from the cookie, if one is set */
var count = parseInt(($.cookie('mytimeout') || 0), 10);

/* set an interval that adds seconds to the count */
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  count++;
  /* plus, you can do something you want to do every second here, 
     like display the countdown to the user */
}, 1000);

/* set a timeout that expires 900000 Milliseconds (15 Minutes) - 
   the already passed time from now */
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
  /* put here what you want to do once the timer epires */

  /* clear the Interval */
  clearInterval(interval);
}, 900000 - count*1000);

/* before the window is reloaded or closed, store the current timeout in a cookie. 
   For cookie options visit jquery-cookie */
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  $.cookie('mytimeout', count, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
};
```

[**Here's a jsfiddle to see it working**](http://jsfiddle.net/TLdp9/4/)

[**And here's a version with buttons to start and reset**](http://jsfiddle.net/TLdp9/6/)

If you want the time to pass even when the user is not on the page, you can use `new Date().getTime()` to get the passed milliseconds between one visit and the next. So change this:

```
/* get the last time the user visited the page */
var lastTime = parseInt(($.cookie('timepassed') || new Date().getTime()), 10);

/* add elapsed time to the count. If the count is negative, set it to 0 */
var count = Math.max(parseInt(($.cookie('mytimeout') || 0), 10) + parseInt((new Date().getTime() - lastTime) / 1000, 10), 0);

/* set the time passed on unload */
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  $.cookie('mytimeout', count, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
  $.cookie('timepassed', new Date().getTime(), { expires: 7, path: '/' });
};
```

[**And yet another jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TLdp9/10/)

**Important: This is not secure, the user can manipulate the count, but if you want to do secure scripting, js is not the right tool for it.**

**UPDATE**

[**A version with hours, minutes and seconds**](http://jsfiddle.net/TLdp9/16/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `localStorage` solution for this. But as you read from the comments, you can manipulate that timer, very easily

This timer won't countdown when the user is not on the page. It just remembers the state of the counter when he leaves. But you know the basic idea. You can make `Date.getTime()` kind of scenario to improve it :P

```
var updateTimer = function() {
    timer = localStorage.getItem('timer') || 0;
    if ( timer === 0 ) {
       $("div#timer").html("Timer is unset");
    } else {
       timer--;
       localStorage.setItem('timer', timer);
      $("div#timer").html(timer);
    }
};

$(function() {
    setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
    $("#start").click( function() {
        localStorage.setItem('timer', 500);
    });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/oqamil/1/edit

Comment: Thanks ;) Pretty much this timer, won't countdown when you are not on the page, so basically it's a wrong strategy anyway :)

Comment: @Stano, you don't have to remove your comment - you can put an answer to this page, which I will upvote :P. Just wanted to notice that the timer written that way, wouldn't be active when the user leaves the page. So if someone turns on the counter and later closes the page, when he open it the countdown will continue from the last time the page was opened. You can fix this by putting in the `localStorage` the time when the counter should finish and setInterval to calculate that time on every minute. :) That's all

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options to persist the time value into a datastorage in the browser using a unload method:
- Cookies
- Localstorage etc

Ideal way - Save the time of starting the workflow on the server in the user session object.
Whenever a reload of the page happens get the value/elapsed time to UI and show the adequate message